# AWS EC2 Instance permissions for S3 buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have multiple EC2 instances which need access to specific different buckets.

For example:

Instance-1  only needs access to bucket-1

Instance-2 only needs access to bucket-2

Therefore I would rather not grant the S3FullAccess policy to my standard EC2 IAM role.

Is it best practice to create a separate IAM role for each EC2 instance and then add all my standard policies (EC2InstanceConnect etc) to it? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Yes, always [best practice](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html) to apply least privilege permissions.

Comment: It is best practice to NEVER use `S3FullAccess`, since that gives permission to do _anything_ in S3, including deleting objects, deleting buckets, making buckets public, etc. Far too dangerous to give to instances and applications. And, frankly, should be given to users in a VERY restricted way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct.  It is the best practice to [attach](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/ec2-instance-access-s3-bucket) to each EC2 instance a specific IAM role that is restricted to the appropriate S3 resource.